# Videos not autoplaying in Safari in 10.12

Tags: safari, macos, video, facebook, twitter

In website sites like Twitter & Facebook, I used to (can’t remember when things “broke”) have videos autoplay, but they no longer do.  (Videos do autoplay correctly in Firefox.)  I can get them to play after I double-click them, which maximizes them to full-screen.  If I minimize back to a std inline video, they continue playing “correctly.”  I have some extensions, but disabling them doesn’t help.  Also, disabling all plugins doesn’t help.  Suggestions to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hidden setting in Safari that disables auto-playback of videos.

To **enable auto-playback**, paste the commands below in Terminal.app (CMD+Space, type "Terminal"). Quit Safari first.

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitMediaPlaybackAllowsInline -bool true
defaults write com.apple.SafariTechnologyPreview WebKitMediaPlaybackAllowsInline -bool true
defaults write com.apple.Safari com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2AllowsInlineMediaPlayback -bool true
defaults write com.apple.SafariTechnologyPreview com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2AllowsInlineMediaPlayback -bool true
```

You may need to reboot your Mac.

To **disable auto-playback** in Safari use the commands below:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitMediaPlaybackAllowsInline -bool false
defaults write com.apple.SafariTechnologyPreview WebKitMediaPlaybackAllowsInline -bool false
defaults write com.apple.Safari com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2AllowsInlineMediaPlayback -bool false
defaults write com.apple.SafariTechnologyPreview com.apple.Safari.ContentPageGroupIdentifier.WebKit2AllowsInlineMediaPlayback -bool false
```

In case this should not work, please let us know if the video-playback works with the [Safari Technology Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/).

Comment: Success! I am not using the tech preview, so only the 1st and 3rd commands in your first block are necessary. No reboot required.